# Passed in values not put into dynamodb

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone explain to me why this api isnt working? Below I have included the API call and the code for the API itself. When I call it, the attributes `siteId`, `userId` and `dateCreated` get uploaded into the db. But the content does not.

API Call:

```
try {
            const attachment = this.file
            ? await s3Upload(this.file)
            : null;

            await this.createSite(this.state.imageText);
                //this.props.history.push("/");
            } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

    createSite(site) {
        return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
          body: site
        });
    }
```

API Code:

```
export async function main(event, context) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: "sites",
    Item: {
      userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      siteId: uuid.v1(),
      content: data.content,
      createdAt: Date.now()
    }
  };
```

I have also tried making the call say content: this.state.imageText but no succ

Comment: what is `data.content` ?   and as first try what about `content : JSON.stringify(data.content)`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi That doesn't work unfortunately